# Unable to order table by another table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm dynamically generating a html table with php and mysql, I'm able to generate it alright but I want to order the table by values from another table, the ordering never works, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
$kids_list = array();
$kids_list[] = '<table border="2"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Group</th></tr>';
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
->select(array('t1.id', 'name', 'lastname', 'group'))->from('kids t1')
->where('year = ' . date("Y"))
->join('LEFT', 'inscriptions t2 ON t1.id = t2.kid')
->order('t2.group ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$l_kids= $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($l_kids as $l_kid) {
  $kids_list[] = '<tr>';
  $kids_list[] = '<td>';
  $kids_list[] = $l_kid->name . ' ' . $l_kid->lastname;
  $kids_list[] = '</td>';
  $kids_list[] = '<td>';
  $kids_list[] = $l_kid->group;
  $kids_list[] = '</td>';
  $kids_list[] = '</tr>';
}
$kids_list[] = '</table>';
return implode($kids_list);
```

I also tried using innerjoin to the same result, it doesn't get ordered at all.

It gets ordered by id from first table, completely ignoring the join.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the query that your abstraction generates and running it directly on the database?

Comment: Can you expand on "never works"? What actually happens, and how does it differ from what you want to happen?

Comment: Is it anything to do with using "group" as a column name? I've avoided using sql keywords for any of mine so I'm not sure of the consequences.

Comment: It's ordering by id of first table, completely ignoring the join

Comment: its not clear what  is meant by "completely ignoring the join"...  I suspect that the generated SQL SELECT statement sent to the database does not match what you are expecting to be sent. (echoing the comment from @El_Vanja , I'd take a peek at the generated SQL text). I have very little experience with Joomla, ... but having the  `->where` before `->join` looks very odd. (In regular SQL SELECT statement, the LEFT JOIN would precede the WHERE clause.... does Joomla reorder those for you? Are there any examples in the Joomla docs that show `->where` preceding `->join`?

Comment: I believe joomla does reorder properly the elements, but, I arranged them as you say anyways, it didn't make a difference